# io7 navigation check when finish transition

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, swipe

I want to mark that my `UINavigationController` is animating (push/pop) or not.

I have a BOOL variable (_isAnimating), and the the code below seem work:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    _isAnimating = YES;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    _isAnimating = NO;
}
```

But it work incorrectly in iOS7 with swipe gesture. Assume my navigation is: root-> view A -> view B . I'm currently on B.

- In begin of swipe (go back from B to A), the funcion "`navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:(BOOL)animated`" is called, then `_isAnimating = YES`.
- The normal case is the swipe is finished (go back to A), the function "`navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:(BOOL)animated`" is called, then `_isAnimating = NO`. This case is OK, but:
- If the user may just swipe a half (half transition to A), then don't want to swipe to the previous view (view A), he go to the current view again (stay B again). Then the function "`navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:(BOOL)animated`" is not called, my variable has incorrect value `(_isAnimating=YES)`.

I have no chance to update my variable in this abnormal case. Is there any way to update the state of navigation? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using the isBeingPresented property of UIViewController?

Comment: Chào! Did you try `viewWillAppear:`?

Comment: @henryeverett
and Thanh-NhonNGUYEN 
isBeingPresented and viewWillAppear: is inside A or B. My code is not A or B, it's another class (it's delegate of UINavigationController, it's role is navigation manager). Beside, my code may have many view, there're A, B, C, D, ..... not only A and B

Comment: Why don't you just keep track of the variable in the viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated and viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated methods of respective VCs? Add a delegate protocol and make the VCs conform to it. That should make your manager capable of receiving callbacks from the VCs if that's what you want.

Comment: @camdaochemgio you got any solution. I'm running into the same issue

Comment: @Tariq Have you resolved it? I had a solution for this. If you still stuck, we can talk

Comment: @camdaochemgio Could you add that solution as an answer? If you do it within 3 days, you will get the bounty of 50 rep.

Answer (score 4):

The clue to solve you problem can be found in the **interactivePopGestureRecognizer** property of **UINavigationController**. This is the recognizer which responds for popping controllers with a swipe gesture. You can notice that the state of the recognizer is changed to **UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded** when the user rises finger up. So, additionally to Navigation Controller delegate you should add target to the Pop Recognizer:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *popRecognizer = self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer;
[popRecognizer addTarget:self                       
                  action:@selector(navigationControllerPopGestureRecognizerAction:)];
```

This action will be called each time the Pop Recognizer changed, including the end of a gesture.

```
- (void)navigationControllerPopGestureRecognizerAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    switch (sender.state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:

        // Next cases are added for relaibility
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:

            _isAnimating = NO;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

P.S. Do not forget that the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` property is available since iOS 7!

Comment: I'm not very good with `UINavigationController`s, how can I detect whether the first or the second view controller will be shown after the animation ended? I have tried using the `navigationController` property, but it is null inside the method. Also the state is not useful, it is always ended in my tests. Any idea how I can detect this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the first" and "the second' controllers? If you need to understand, whether the user has finished the gesture, or not, you can add a flag `_swipeCompleted` and set it to `YES` inside the `didShowViewController` method. You also may look at `viewControllers` property of the Navigation Controller, it always contain all controllers in the stack. And if you need to know which controller will be shown *before* the animation ends, use variable `viewController` which is passed to `willShowViewController`.